# Multithreaded method to call API in Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need to implement multi-threading in Springboot while calling API with POST method. I am pulling records from oracle database based on a SELECT query, then using RowMapper go through each record one by one. In next step, I am just calling a method to send these records to API to send these records in the form of postmapping and get the records back.

As the select query can return 10,20 or 100 records at a time. Calling each record one by one won't be ideal. I was thinking if I can send these multiple records at a time. I am not sure how to achieve it as I am new to Springboot and still learning it.

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

import com.demo.payengine.api.ProviderUpdateAPI;
import com.demo.payengine.config.DataSourceDbConfig;
import com.demo.payengine.pojo.ProvRecordMappingPOJO;

public class ProvRecordProcessing {
    
    //declare variables
    private static String tn_id                     ;
    private static String pr_id                     ; 
    private static String pr_entity                 ;
    private static String pr_cl_eft_ind             ;    
    private static String pr_edi_dest_ind           ; 
    private static String pr_ra_dest_ind            ; 
    private static String br_id                     ; 
    private static String br_account_no             ; 
    private static String br_account_name           ; 
    private static String br_account_number_qual    ;

    @Autowired
    DataSourceDbConfig dbConfig;
    
    @Autowired
    ProviderUpdateAPI provUpdate;
    
    DataSource dataSource;
    
    
    public void dbProvRecordProcessing() {
        
        dataSource = dbConfig.dataSource();
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        
        
        String sqlQuery ="tn_id, pr_id, pr_entity, pr_cl_eft_ind, pr_edi_dest_ind, pr_ra_dest_ind, \r\n" + 
                "br_id, br_account_no, br_account_name, br_account_number_qual\r\n" + 
                "from mc_pr_prv pr \r\n" + 
                "inner join sg_prb_enrll_fl enroll\r\n" + 
                "on pr.tn_id = enroll.pr_payee_id\r\n" + 
                "inner join mc_mbr_bank_rel br\r\n" + 
                "on br.br_ck = pr.br_ck\r\n" + 
                "where pr.pr_entity ='G'";
        
        
        RowMapper<ProvRecordMappingPOJO> rowMapper = new RowMapper<ProvRecordMappingPOJO>(){

            @Override
            public ProvRecordMappingPOJO mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                tn_id                   = rs.getString("tn_id")                     ;
                pr_id                   = rs.getString("pr_id")                     ;
                pr_entity               = rs.getString("pr_entity")                 ;
                pr_cl_eft_ind           = rs.getString("pr_cl_eft_ind")             ;
                pr_edi_dest_ind         = rs.getString("pr_edi_dest_ind ")          ;
                br_id                   = rs.getString("br_id")                     ;
                br_account_no           = rs.getString("br_account_no")             ;
                br_account_name         = rs.getString("br_account_name")           ;
                br_account_number_qual  = rs.getString("br_account_number_qual")    ;
                
                
                return new ProvRecordMappingPOJO(tn_id, pr_id, pr_entity, pr_cl_eft_ind, pr_edi_dest_ind, 
                        pr_ra_dest_ind, br_id, br_account_no, br_account_name, br_account_number_qual);
                }
            };
        
        //intialize sql query
        List<ProvRecordMappingPOJO> provRecords = jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, rowMapper);
        
        for(ProvRecordMappingPOJO record : provRecords) {
            
            System.out.println("Processing provider record.." + record);
            
            //This method will call API <--- how to make it multi threaded
            provUpdate.provUpdateAPI(tn_id, pr_id, pr_entity, pr_cl_eft_ind, pr_edi_dest_ind, pr_ra_dest_ind, 
                    br_id, br_account_no, br_account_name, br_account_number_qual); 
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling method as `provUpdate.provUpdateAPI(tn_id, ..)`, why not as `provUpdate.provUpdateAPI(record)`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class `ProvUpdateExecutor` which takes a `ProvUpdateResult` object. For readability I'm encapsulating all method argument in below method with `ProvUpdateResult` object

```
provUpdate.provUpdateAPI(tn_id, pr_id, pr_entity, pr_cl_eft_ind, pr_edi_dest_ind, pr_ra_dest_ind, 
                    br_id, br_account_no, br_account_name, br_account_number_qual);
```

`ProvUpdateExecutor` class responsibility is to execute API calls in multi-threaded way

```
public class ProvUpdateExecutor {

  private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(noThreads);
  private ProviderUpdateAPI providerUpdateAPI;

  public ProvUpdateExecutor(ProviderUpdateAPI providerUpdateAPI) {
    this.providerUpdateAPI = providerUpdateAPI;
  }

  public void execute(List<ProvUpdateResult> provUpdateResults) {
    List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ProvUpdateResult provUpdateResult : provUpdateResults) {
      futures.add(executorService.submit(() -> providerUpdateAPI.provUpdateAPI(provUpdateResult)));
    }

    for (Future<?> future : futures) {
      try {
        future.get();
      } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Where `noThreads` is configurable (passed through configuration parameter). Please note there is cost associated with creation of thread pool so you might want to create this class as `singleton` abject.

In your method call `provUpdateExecutor.execute(provUpdateResults)` outside loop

Answer (score -1):

Better option might be CompletableFuture API, create list of CompletableFutureAPI of api calls and join then together, once all of those gets completed extract the result.

Check these 2 web pages:

1. This will give a practical use case for your need -> https://theboreddev.com/combining-multiple-api-calls-with-completablefuture/
2. This will give a better idea of running and joining multiple completableFuture's in parallel and together -> https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture#Multiple